# How is this themed when using views

Tags: views, theming

I have a single page template...there are 5 sections, each powered by a view bound to a single content type.

The first section has a dark blue background, the second green, third red, etc...

each section renders it's "rows" differently...first section might have the header as  and the body wrapped as

. Ther second might have alternating left and right aligned images.

This visual layout that is so common today is quite difficult to accomplish (if not impossible?) using default drupal template suggestions.

What I have basically had to do is iterate $view->result inside views-view--block.tpl.php and render each section individually this way to achieve the desired effect...

Is there a different/alternative way of themeing views to match the markup provided by someone else?

Not sure if this question is appropriate here (borderline I am sure) however I am not sure where else to ask or look.

Alex

Answer (score 1):

In static markup normally one has row level classes, element level classes and wrapper classes. By looking into those classes add exactly the same classes into your views interface, or override default template and add your markup and then render your block in appropriate region